# Window manager looks weird in VNC or rdp

Tags: vnc

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I can log in lightdm successfully.

But if I log in Ubuntu in remote client via VNC or Xrdp, the desktop is very weird. Please check the screen-shot below.

[image]

I used apt-get to install tightvncserver and xrdp, all settings by default.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add the your .vnc/xstartup config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the session properly. Unity is the default shell in Ubuntu, and since it cannot be used with RDP and similar, it will fail to start when you use the default Gnome Session. Therefore you need to add --session=ubuntu-2d to the session preferences. That will tell it to use Unity 2D instead of Unity.

Comment: Thank you. I set the session to ubuntu-2d, then I can view the desktop normally.

Comment: I have the same problem, could you tell me where is the session preferences file located? Or in other work